# Is it possible to add a database filed to the existing database table without rails g migration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration

I am new to Ruby on Rails, so I have some confusion about rails migration.

I want to add a field on my user table, according to rails documentation is only possible by using

```
rails generate migration add_field_name_to_table_name field_name: type
```

**Question**

Is it possible to add fields to the existing database table without rails g migration in rails? Thanks...

Comment: yes it is, you can just open your DBMS(Postgres, MySQL, etc), and run your SQL command to add that field. If you do that, you'll lose all the stuff that Rails does for you when it comes to database, for example, you can't just run `rails db:migrate` anymore because that field will be missing. So, if someone else joins your team, you'll have to give them the schema of your database so that they have the same thing. You'll also lose database versioning, etc. So, I'd suggest you to stick with Rails migrations.

Comment: Thanks @fanta for this explanation

Answer (score 0):

The bigger question is why you need to do that. I mean to imply that whatever makes you think that you need to do this is wrong (I am pretty confident about it, assuming you are a new rails user). It is like you would leave your plane without a reason for a long-distance flight to travel by foot.

**Answer:**

You can do that by:

- logging in to Postgres manually like `rails db`
- then creating table manually the SQL way
- then adding the table manually with correct columns in your `schema.rb` file
- then creating a model manually

You still will have to repeat this every time this project is cloned anywhere else with no window for mistake. With migration, on the other hand, you will just need to do `rails db:migrate`

Happy Coding.